# send email with email module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

when I try to send an email with email module I get  error
I tried with 3 different mail provider
and it is my code :

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib



message = MIMEMultipart()
message["from"] = "Amir Mohammad Fallah"
message["to"] = "*******@gmail.com"
message["subject"] = "python test message"
message.attach(MIMEText("body"))  

password = "*******"
user = "*********@gmail.com"
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:  # port 587 for icloud  and 25 for aol 
    
    smtp.ehlo() 
    smtp.login(user, password)
    smtp.send_message(message)
    print("it's Done !")
```

and I after while I got this errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mgxc2/PycharmProjects/Advance/Python.py", line 588, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:  # port 587 for icloud  and 25 for aol #mail.cortatech.ir port 587
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I think you should change `with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 465)`  to  `with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)`  and see what happens... Secondly, you should change your Internet connection, because your code looks okay to me.. but I'll check it soon to know the cause, but first try the corrections I sent across

Answer (score 0):

You should use port `587` because it's the default mail submission port.

Here is an [articles](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/) that explain witch SMTP port to use for witch action.